# C: How can I read unkown number of integers inside parenthesis from input?

Tags: c

It's quite bothering when reading unknown number of integers within a pair of parenthesis.

For example:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

But We don't how many integers there are.

Rather than reading them entirely as a string, can anyone have any other ideas to fix that?

Many thanks.

Comment: assuming you're reading from a file, `man 3 fgetc` and `man 3 fscanf` if you're feeling adventurous. if you're talking about variadic parameter lists, completely different answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I really think he wants to parse the comma separated value list into individual integers...so your answer is more relavent

Answer (score 2):

It is terribly unclear what you really want from the posted question. But if you're talking about variable length arguments to a function, then: 
Look into [Variable arguments](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html) in C.

If you are talking about reading unknown no. of integers from input buffer, then you'll have to make your own function to read character by character, parsing the input for numbers, parenthesis and commas: A basic parser to do that is below(note, its not tested and can contain bugs) - understand and modify it accordingly. You can read in any no. of integers with this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum { START, OPAREN, CPAREN, COMMA, DIGIT, EOF_S,UNKNOWN }Token;
int c;
unsigned char state = 0;
int numbers[100];

Token getToken(FILE *f)
{
   while(isspace(c = fgetc(f)));
   if(c == EOF) return EOF_S;
   if(c == '(') return OPAREN;
   if(c == ',') return COMMA;
   if(c == ')') return CPAREN;
   if(isdigit(c)) return DIGIT;
   return UNKNOWN;
}

int getNumber(FILE *f)
{
   int returnNumber = 0;
   Token tok = START;
   while(tok != DIGIT){ 
     tok = getToken(f);
     if(tok == UNKNOWN){ state = 1; return 0x0FFFFFFF;}
     if(tok == EOF_S) { state = 2; return 0x0FFFFFFF;} 
   } 
   if(tok == DIGIT){
      while(tok == DIGIT){
         returnNumber = returnNumber * 10 + (c - '0');
         tok =getToken(f);
      }
   }
   return returnNumber;
}

int getNumbers(FILE *f, int *numbers_0)
{
   int number;
   int no_counter = 0;
   while(((number = getNumber(f)) != 0x0FFFFFFF) && (state == 0)){
      numbers_0[no_counter++] = number;
   }
   return no_counter; //returns no. of numbers between ( and ), separated by ','
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int no, i;
   no = getNumbers(stdin,numbers);
   if(no > 100) no = 100;
   for(i = 0; i < no; i++){
     printf("%d\n",numbers[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here after a simple C code to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x; char c='\0';

    scanf("%*[(]");

    while (c != ')' && scanf("%d %c", &x, &c)==2){

        if (c!=',' && c != ')') {
            printf ("format error in the input\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Number: %d\n", x);
    }
}
```

If your input stream is `stdin` then use `scanf` as indicated in the above code

If your input stream is a `file` then use `fscanf`

Answer (score 0):

if u need only read ( and processing right now) u can

1. read char C until C=='('
2. read char C if it space/tab/CR/LF continue step 2 else step 3
3. if C==')' End of reading list
4. so if u here c is a digit so u can getback char( use ungetc(C,stdin) ) and reread all number as integer .here u can opirate with intger as u wish. continue to 2.

If list is syntax correct  above algo enogh  else add where read C test on EOF and on step 4 test on alpha.

I think u can rewrite algo using C without goto.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for a function implementation with variable arguments, below snippet will help you.

```
int add(int *total, int count, ...)
{
   int i = 0;
   va_list numbers;
   va_start(numbers, count);
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       *total += va_arg(numbers, int);
   } 
   va_end(numbers);
}
```

You can call this function like

```
...
int result = 0;
add(&result, 3, 10, 20, 30);
...
```